# need to login to devise account on a different domain / subdomain with click of a button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, subdomain

I have an app where an admin has his own site / login through devise.   The admin can then create other subdomains with thier own admin user.

The admin can then see all their child / subdomain account when they login.

Problem is i want them to be able to click 'Login as admin' for any of the accounts / subdomains and then it to redirect to that subdomain and log them in.

So i need to go from say www.example.com to site1.example.com and sign them in as the admin in background.

Any ideas how to do this ?

I see the sign_in method that devise has but i need to somehow let it know i want it to signt he user to a different subdomain admin.

Also this subdomain might not be a subdomain but using their own domain name.

Any help on this would be great!!

thanks a lot
Rick

Comment: https://github.com/flyerhzm/switch_user inspiration

Comment: thanks @clyfe i can switch user on same domain with the sign_in method by devise but only on the same domain not onto a different one.   Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using your own views (not the one generated by devise), you can switch from one domain to another with the helper:

```
resource_url(:subdomain => 'site1')
```

Then you can override the generated routes like this:

```
Testapp::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'home#index'

  constraints :subdomain => 'site1' do
    resources :forums
  end
end
```